# Custom code snippets not appearing in Visual Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio, code-snippets

I create a code snippet to use when editing php files. However, when I select Insert Snippet, my snippet doesn't appear in the list of snippets.

If I display the Code Snippet Manager and select PHP as the language, my snippets folder is displayed. If I expand that folder, I see my snippet (which is saved in that folder with the *.snippet file extension). I've also re-selected the Import button to re-import that snippet. It imports without any errors.

However, when I choose Insert Snippet when editing a php file, the intellisense menu only shows ASP.NET, ASP.NET Web Stack 5, and HTML in the menu. It doesn't show my snippet folder name or my snippet.

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I didn't find a solution.

Comment: How about now? :D